# SharePoint - retrieve sharing links for a folder

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I have SharePoint folders that are shared with external users.

The sharing is created using ShareDocument() in OfficeDevPnP.Core. 
(Thanks to Jack Le for answering [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56279481/how-to-share-a-sharepoint-folder-with-an-external-user-without-requiring-a-micro) on how to do this)

I now want to retrieve the email addresses that a folder is shared with, ie this list:

[[image]]

I've tried these methods, but can't get the information I require:

```
GetSharingLinkData() 
GetSharingLinkKind() 
GetObjectSharingSettings()
GetObjectSharingSettingsForDocument()
```

Is there a way to retrieve the email addresses?

Comment: Were you able to get this info?

Comment: No.
It seems that SharePoint creates a group for the folder, and the users that the folder is shared with are added to the group. I was able to retrieve the group header details but not the users in the group.

Answer (score 1):

There is a rest api endpoint that could offer this kind of info.

```
_api/web/Lists(@a1)/GetItemById(@a2)/GetSharingInformation
```

[image]

Refer to below blog to get more details:

- https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2018/04/04/externally-sharing-getsharinginformation-rest-api/

BR

Answer (score 0):

The rest call above and described on Cann0nf0dder web site only works in the browser when using Sharepoint interface.  If you try it programmatically it results in "Method not allowed".  I don't think it is useable.

Below is a list of usable commands in the Sharepoint rest interface, and GetSharingInformation is not one of them:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/jj860569(v=office.15)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 0):

The answer of [Billy Bonkers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65847674/4689582) is not correct: The decribed REST endpoint of Cann0nf0dder can be used.

He has used it on the next part of the series: https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2018/04/05/externally-sharing-spfx-isexternallyshared-field-customizer

"Method not allowed" error is a result when using wrong HTTP-Method: POST must be used.

In dependence of the scenario you must additionally provide a FormDigest manually:

- execute a POST request to **/_api/ContextInfo**
- get the **FormDigestValue** property from the resulting JSON
- use this value to set the **X-RequestDigest** header property for the **/_api/web/Lists(@a1)/GetItemById(@a2)/GetSharingInformation** POST request